# Why scroll events don't work?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

Why scroll events don't work?
but MouseWheel  works.
Is it something I missed?

```
    AddHandler browserView1.Scroll, AddressOf ScrollChange
    AddHandler browserView1.MouseWheel, AddressOf MouseWheelChange



 //Not running
 Public Sub ScrollChange(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs)
    Debug.Print("Scroll")
 End Sub

 //run
 Public Sub MouseWheelChange(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

    Debug.Print("MouseWheel")
 end sub
```

Comment: Do you mean the ScrollableControl.Scroll event?